# Programmatically edit TreeView/TreeItem

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-8

**Edit #2**: Since it looks like a bug i already posted a bug report in the [javaFx-jira](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089497). You have to have an account to have access to the issue. I will keep this post up-to-date, if there is new information.

**Original post:**
I have a simple UI with a button and a TreeView. If the button gets pressed there should be a new item added to the TreeView. This item should be editable as soon as it appears in the tree.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class ClientController {

    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> tree;

    public void initialize() {
        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.setCellFactory(p -> new TextFieldTreeCell<>(new DefaultStringConverter()));

        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
        root.setValue("Items");
        root.setExpanded(true);

        tree.setRoot(root);
    }

    @FXML
    public void createItem() {
        TreeItem<String> newItem = new TreeItem<>();
        newItem.setValue("Item " + tree.getExpandedItemCount());

        tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(newItem);
        tree.requestFocus();
        tree.getSelectionModel().select(newItem);
        tree.edit(newItem);
    }
}
```

The CellFactory i am using is [part of the JavaFX api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTreeCell.html).

If I have a look at the api-documentation ([TreeView#edit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#edit-javafx.scene.control.TreeItem-)) there is not much to do on my site.

Many examples I found via google like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm#BABFCCCG) create a context-menu for each TreeItem. Useful, but not exactly what i want, right now.

If I select/double-click the item in the UI I am able to edit any previously created and existing TreeItem. Do I miss something?

**Edit #1:**

If the createItem method gets changed to the following code:

```
@FXML
public void createItem() throws InterruptedException {
    TreeItem<String> newItem = new TreeItem<>();
    newItem.setValue("Item " + this.tree.getExpandedItemCount());

    this.tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(newItem);
    this.tree.requestFocus();
    this.tree.getSelectionModel().select(newItem);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleController.this.tree.edit(newItem);
        }
    });
}
```

every new item is correctly marked for edit (the created textfield and its content are selected). 
Using [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) without *Thread.sleep* doesnt work and *Thread.sleep* without *runLater* neither.

This simply does not feel right. What is my problem?

I provide a very small example (eclipse) project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/duos0ynw4rqp3yn/Test.zip?dl=0
containing The main-method, the FXML-File and the "problematic" controller.

Comment: argh. Now i posted my question and suddenly i find another (sadly unanswered) question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481205/explicitly-calling-edit-on-a-treeview-cell)

Comment: looks like a bug to me - you might consider reporting it so it has a chance to getting fixed

Comment: @kleopatra i am afraid youre right. i will do some research on the JavaFX Jira platform and may file a bug if i cannot find some help there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TreeCells (that is their content and binding to the treeItem) are updated lazily in a layout pass, that is very "late" when the next pulse is fired. A Platform.runLater(..) or any hard-coded delay may happen before or after that pulse, that's (probably) why both seem to work or not spuriously.

So another whacky hack is to manually force a re-layout on the tree after having added a new item and before programatically starting an edit:

```
root.getChildren().add(newItem);
tree.layout();
tree.edit(newItem);
```

Needless to say, that this shouldn't be necessary - the current behaviour is a severe bug and must be fixed at once (... meaning ... jdk 9)

Comment: this answer renders the sleep and PauseTransition unnecessary. it works. Thanks. if i cannot find any comparable bug i will report a new one soon on the JavaFX-Jira.

Comment: Brilliant. Five or more years later, using JavaFX 13, I still find this is necessary. Would you still qualify it as a "severe bug"? Or is there some design rationale of some kind behind it?

Comment: @mikerodent good question - with an answer like radio eriwan _yes, but..._ ;) From the top of my head (didn't check recently) the _but_ branch means, that there does not seem to be any easy (a bit of an understatement ;) - way out: this doing layout during a layout is a (bad, IMO) habit deeply interwoven with the overall design, changing that would be too much risk. BTW: would tree.refresh help (vs. layout)?

Answer (score 5):

It seems, the treeView is needing more time to do its internal calculations before the newly added item got reflected to it. To determine exactly which calculations are causing the problem, one need to dig the source code and see what is going on under the hood.

The workaround is to force treeView do its calculation immediately,

```
@FXML
public void createItem() throws InterruptedException {
    TreeItem<String> newItem = new TreeItem<>();
    newItem.setValue("Item " + tree.getExpandedItemCount());

    tree.getRoot().getChildren().add(newItem);

    // Trigger whatever calculations there internally
    TreeItem<String> r = tree.getRoot();
    tree.setRoot( null );
    tree.setRoot( r );

    tree.requestFocus();
    tree.getSelectionModel().select(newItem);
    tree.edit(newItem);
}
```

This workaround was found totally intuitively based on other bugs in JavaFX ;-)

---

Alternatively, since Platform.runlaters's postponed time is obviously not enough, you may use `PauseTransition` to increase the time needed:

```
PauseTransition p = new PauseTransition( Duration.millis( 100 ) );
p.setOnFinished( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle( ActionEvent event )
    {
        tree.edit( newItem );
    }
} );
p.play();
```

Comment: the documenation of Platform.runLater states the call will happen at 'some unspecified time'. This is what i experienced too. Very rarley it was working with *runLater* on its own. By using the PauseTransition the UI stays responsive, but still, since i have to hardcode the time, the transition will wait there may be some machines where it is still not enough. Not speaking of bad user-experience. Since it is still not the correct answer to my question i will postpone the acceptance. I will have a look at the FX-Jira Platform.

Comment: @UlukBiy since this is more "ugly" then forcing the layout directly i choose kleopatras answer over yours. nevertheless it is working. So +1 from me too.